# Fire engine red paint

Tags: meaning, compounds, adjuncts

> Unlike HTML, which reveals itself in flashy text and graphics, XML is more of an under-the-hood kind of technology. If HTML is the **fire engine red paint** and supple leather interior of a sports car, XML is the turbocharged engine and sport suspension. Okay, maybe the sports car analogy is a bit much, but you get the idea that XML's impact on the Web is hard to see with the naked eye. However, the benefits are directly realized in all kinds of different ways.

My understanding is **fire engine red** is used as an adjective:
- What kind of **paint**?
- **Red paint**. What kind of **red paint**?
- **Fire engine red paint**. Meaning, the kind of red they use to paint fire trucks.

Is that correct?

Comment: You've got it exactly right. This refers to the very bright red that is commonly seen on fire trucks, and is also a popular sports car paint color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you surmise, *[fire engine red](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fire-engine%20red)* is a reference to bright reds traditionally applied to firefighting equipment such as fire trucks and fire alarms.

[image: NYFD fire truck from Wikimedia Commons]

In practice, [colors of fire engines vary widely](http://www.nema.org/Standards/Pages/American-National-Standard-for-Safety-Colors.aspx) and unlike "[National School Bus Glossy Yellow](http://www.nhtsa.gov/nhtsa/whatsup/tea21/tea21programs/402guide.html)" (a.k.a. *chrome yellow* or *school bus yellow*) or "[safety orange](http://www.nema.org/Standards/Pages/American-National-Standard-for-Safety-Colors.aspx)" and its counterparts, *fire engine red* refers to no single hue.